# What's $/$ in the context of Fourier transforms? E.g. $H/G$

Tags: fourier-transform

So in Wikipedia's article for Deconvolution, it's given that the deconvolution of

$$f * g = h$$

is

$$F = H/G$$

where $F, H, G$ are Fourier transforms of $f,g,h$.

But what does $/$ mean? Is it division? Then how to divide Fourier transform with a Fourier transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the usual (point-wise) division of two functions. The Fourier transform of a function is another function.

The result $F=H/G$ comes from the fact that the Fourier transform of a convolution is the product of the Fourier transforms, this is known as the [Convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

Comment: But if the functions are continuous, then how does one actually compute the division? Or is it in practice convolved as a discrete approximation? E.g. for a 1024-point FFT?

Comment: One computes it point-wise, for every $x$, the value $F(x)$ is given by $F(x) = H(x)/G(x)$, this is just a division of numbers.

Comment: But there are infinite amount of points that a continuous function attains in an interval?

Comment: Yes, it is defined in all those points like so.

Comment: But how does one compute it, because you cannot list an infinite amount of points?

Comment: Why do you need to list the points. You know the $H$ and $G$ (the Fourier transforms of $h$ and $g$), right?

Comment: Or are you talking about how to compute the convolution $f*g$?

Comment: $H$,$G$, just as any continuous function, get infinite amount of values in any interval. It's impossible to calculate an infinite number of values, because they never end.

Comment: The function $s(x) = x^2$ gets infinite amount of values in any interval, do you have trouble calculating it?

Comment: @mavavilj In general the (linear) map $f \mapsto f \ast g $ is inversible iff ($G$ the Fourier transform of $g$) doesn't vanish, so $H(x)/G(x)$ is well-defined as a function, and by the convolution theorem it is $F$ the Fourier transform of $f$, so we can take its inverse Fourier transform. In real life, it often happens $f \mapsto f \ast g $ is *not* inversible, but we will compute anyway a *best approximation* to $f$ in some sense.

Comment: @ploosu2 Yes, because I can never finish such calculation, because there are infinite amount of values. What I was trying to ask is that surely in practice this would be calculated using a discrete Fourier transform?

Comment: @mavavilj Not necessarily, you could have a formula for the outcome. Then how you actually compute the value at a given point comes down to calculating with that formula.

Comment: Obviously @mavavilj is thinking about how to do it in a computer. Perhaps he (or she?) hasn't even realized that in mathematics we work in a world where things don't have to be finite.